# SpreadsheetGear fonts look blurred compared to Excel

Tags: c#, excel, fonts, spreadsheetgear

I'm evaluating the SpreadsheetGear component for Excel file manipulation. However, out of the box the fonts look slightly blurred or hazy when the same spreadsheet is viewed side-by-side with Excel. Is there some anti-aliasing setting I'm missing?

Or is this by design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone else wondering, I logged with support and it is apparently by design.

> The reason for the text not being
>   clear is the fact that we use
>   anti-aliased fonts. We have spent
>   quite a bit of time trying to get non
>   anti-aliased fonts to work. However,
>   .NET does not provide reliable font
>   metrics when anti-aliased fonts are
>   not used, and we cannot do some of the
>   layout we need to do without reliable
>   font metrics. Performance is also
>   slower when non anti-aliased text is
>   used.
>
> If Microsoft fixes this (the font
>   metrics issues) in a future version of
>   .NET, we may add an option to use non
>   anti-aliased text.
>
> There are some advantages to
>   anti-aliased text. As users move to
>   higher resolution (120+ DPI instead of
>   96 DPI) the appearance of anti-aliased
>   text improves significantly. There are
>   also other advantages, such as
>   reliable zooming. Try autofitting some
>   columns in Excel/SpreadsheetGear and
>   then zoom in and out - notice that the
>   text no longer fits in Excel but it
>   still fits in SpreadsheetGear. Moving
>   workbooks between 96 DPI and 120 DPI
>   is also more reliable with
>   anti-aliased text. Printed output also
>   looks better in many cases.

Comment: Re-opening this topic 3 years after. Sadly, the point is not anti-aliased font VS non-anti-aliased font. In fact, Excel uses anti-aliasing too. The difference is in the AA engine and its settings. For example, Photoshop and Flash offers many AA settings to get a sharper result. Maybe .net do not?

Answer (score 0):

SpreadsheetGear may be ClearType compatible. You may want to experiment with turning ClearType off in your Windows display settings, and seeing if that makes any difference to you.

Cheers

Comment: It does look like that kind of blurring, but I see it with ClearType on and off. Running on Windows 7 in case that matters.